# Shuffle a deck of cards, using the overhand shuffle method

Tags: clojure, playing-cards, shuffle

I've started learning Clojure, after many years of Java. As one of a series of exercises, I'm writing a simple card game, and the `overhand-shuffle` function is shown below.

My main concerns are:

1. Most of my code appears inside the `let`, and to me it looks more procedural than functional, is this the best way to do this? Please bear in mind that the reasons I did it this way are:

   - I wanted to avoid having the body of the function as one big, monolithic block of dense, unreadable code
   - Binding lots of symbols like this chops the code into manageable pieces, making it easier for me to read and understand intermediate steps
   - Debugging is also easier, as I can examine what's happening at each step
2. In my `reduce`, I'm passing back two values on each iteration (stored in the map `result`). These are `:cards` (which contains cards not yet allocated) and `:new-cards` (which builds up the new version of shuffled cards). However, I'm only interested in the new, shuffles cards being passed back as the result of the `reduce`, not the intermediate results that `reduce` needs at each step. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

```
(defn overhand-shuffle
  "Shuffle the cards, using the overhand shuffle technique.
  REFL https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuffling#Overhand_shuffle"
  [cards]
  (let [number-of-cards   (count cards)
        number-of-slices  (/ (* number-of-cards 7) 52)
        max-slice-size    (int (/ (* number-of-cards 0.6) number-of-slices))

        ; Randomly determine the size of the little slices we will take
        slice-sizes
          (for [_i (range number-of-slices)]
            (inc (rand-int max-slice-size))
            )

        slice-total       (apply + slice-sizes)
        top-card-count    (- number-of-cards slice-total)

        ; Take the top cards, and make slices out of the remaining cards
        top-cards         (take top-card-count cards)
        slice-cards       (drop top-card-count cards)

        ; Chop up the slices, and return with them in reverse order
        slices
          (reduce
            (fn [result slice-size]
              (let [cards     (:cards result)
                    new-cards (:new-cards result)

                    ; Take a slice, being the first n of the remaining cards
                    slice     (take slice-size cards)
                    ]
                ; Return with the remaining cards and the growing list of new cards
                {:cards     (drop slice-size cards)
                 :new-cards (concat slice new-cards)}
                )
              )
            ; initial results we will start the reduce with
            {:cards slice-cards :new-cards nil}

            ; iterate over the list of slice sizes
            slice-sizes)
        ]
    ; We have what we need, so return with the slices on top of the remaining cards
    (concat
      ; The slices that came from the bottom of the cards
      (:new-cards slices)

      ; Add what used to be the top cards, after the slices
      top-cards
      )
    )
  )

(defn test-shuffle
  "Simple invocation of shuffle, to show result"
  []
  (let [simple-cards (range 1 53)
        shuffle-times 10]
    (loop [count shuffle-times
           cards simple-cards]
      (if (< count 0)
        cards
        (recur (dec count) (overhand-shuffle cards))
        )
      )
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick disclaimer: I am not really a clojure developer so take any of my recommendations with a pinch of salt.

Regarding your giant let:  I don't think that's necessarily a bad thing to do, but in some cases it might be worth splitting some of it off into separate functions.  For example `max-slice-size` and `number-of-slices` are only really needed to generate `slice-sizes`, so it may be worth splitting them off into a `make-slice-sizes` function or something.

Most of the reasons you listed for having things in a giant let are actually really good reasons to use smaller functions:

- You've got a selection of smaller functions rather than the big dense mono-function you were trying to avoid.
- Your individual functions are your manageable pieces, rather than each binding of the let.  You can call them from a repl, or write tests of just those individual functions to make sure they are behaving as expected.
- Debugging is also still possible, but with the benefit that it's easier to use a repl & write tests.

A few points about your reduce:

- You can simplify it a bit by returning a vector instead of a map and using argument destructuring instead of getting the values out of the map.
- When you want to do a take & a drop using the same numbers it's usually easier to use `split-at`.
- Passing back 2 things from a reduce doesn't seem wrong.  However I would consider just using your reduce to build up a list of slices that you can manipulate afterwards rather than using concat to actually do the shuffling within the reduce.  The `reductions` function can help with this - it is like reduce, but it returns the intermediate steps that you can manipulate later.
- Currently you are building up a list of random slice sizes, and then writing some more code to handle the remainder of the cards (`top-cards` in your code).  I think you could simplify your code a fair bit by just treating this as another slice and adding it in to your `slice-sizes` sequence.

I've had a go at implementing my suggestions, and ended up with this:

```clj
(defn overhand-shuffle
  "Shuffle the cards, using the overhand shuffle technique.
  REFL https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuffling#Overhand_shuffle"
  [cards]
  (let [slice-sizes        (make-slice-sizes (count cards))
        ; The first value returned by reductions is the initial value, so we
        ; drop it here.
        [_ & slices]       (map first
                             (reductions (fn [[_ remaining-cards] slice-size]
                                           (split-at slice-size remaining-cards))
                                         [nil cards]
                                         slice-sizes))]
    (apply concat (reverse slices))))

(defn- make-slice-sizes
  "Randomly determine the size of the little slices we will take"
  [number-of-cards]
  (let [number-of-slices  (/ (* number-of-cards 7) 52)
        max-slice-size    (int (/ (* number-of-cards 0.6) number-of-slices))
        slice-sizes       (map inc (repeatedly
                                    number-of-slices
                                    #(rand-int max-slice-size)))
        remaining-cards   (- number-of-cards (apply + slice-sizes))]
    ;; We need to make sure all our cards get "shuffled", so add a slice of the
    ;; remaining cards on the end of our list of slices
    (concat slice-sizes [remaining-cards])))
```

Please let me know if I've explained any of this badly, and I'll try and improve it.

Edit: You can actually take this a bit further and split out your reduction into a function as well:

```clj
(defn build-slices
  "Builds a sequence of slices from cards.
   The sizes of the slices are determined using slice-sizes"
  [cards slice-sizes]
  ;; Perform a reduction where the first element of each step is the slice,
  ;; and the second element is the remaining cards.  Use a let binding to get
  ;; rid of the first reduction, because it is just the initial value we
  ;; passed in.
  (let [[_ & slices]  (map first
                          (reductions (fn [[_ remaining-cards] slice-size]
                                        (split-at slice-size remaining-cards))
                                      [nil cards]
                                      slice-sizes))]
    slices))
```

Which allows you to simplify your `overhand-shuffle` function further:

```clj
(defn overhand-shuffle
  "Shuffle the cards, using the overhand shuffle technique.
  REFL https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuffling#Overhand_shuffle"
  [cards]
  (let [slice-sizes   (make-slice-sizes (count cards))
        slices        (build-slices cards slice-sizes)]
    (apply concat (reverse slices))))
```

Since both these functions are now just a series of steps each building on the last you *could* rewrite using one of the threading macros (`->` or `->>`).  These let you list a series of forms and automatically insert the result of the last form into the next form, as either the first (for `->`) or the last (for `->>`) parameter to each of them.  This allows you to make your function a series of "steps" that transform your input data, a bit like your original `let` bindings, but without the intermediate variables:

```clj
(defn build-slices
  "Builds a sequence of slices from cards.
   The sizes of the slices are determined using slice-sizes"
  [cards slice-sizes]
  (->> slice-sizes
       ;; Perform a reduction where the first element of each step is the slice,
       ;; and the second element is the remaining cards.
       (reductions (fn [[_ remaining-cards] slice-size]
                     (split-at slice-size remaining-cards))
                   [nil cards])
       ;; Drop the first element, as it is just our initial [nil, cards] value.
       (drop 1)
       ;; Extract each of the slices.
       (map first)))

(defn overhand-shuffle
  "Shuffle the cards, using the overhand shuffle technique.
  REFL https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuffling#Overhand_shuffle"
  [cards]
  (->> cards
       (count)
       (make-slice-sizes)
       (build-slices cards)
       (reverse)
       (apply concat)))
```

A bonus edit: the loop in your `test-shuffle` function is very procedural.  Could be better with `iterate`:

```clj
(defn test-shuffle
  "Simple invocation of shuffle, to show result"
  []
  (let [simple-cards (range 1 53)
        shuffle-times 10]
    (nth (iterate overhand-shuffle simple-cards) shuffle-times)))
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks for that. There's such a huge number of ideas here like argument destructuring, private functions, and functions like `reductions` and `split-at` that I wasn't aware of. Thank you again!!

Comment: @SteveMoseley no problem - I actually enjoyed putting this together, don't get to use clojure anywhere near as much as I'd like.